# Delete Rows From Merge Document If Cell In Excel Is Blank

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

i have created a mailmerge using VBA which automatically saves each entry as its own PDF. The only problem i am running into is that some of the cells in excel are empty and pull through blank. The document being used for the mailmerge is set out in a table to make it look nicer and separating the mergefields is easier this way. I am wanting to create some code so if a cell is empty, instead of it bringing through a blank space, it instead deletes that row from the table in the merge document. I have been playing around with the MyDoc.tables(1).Rows().Delete but cannot seem to get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub RunMailMerge()
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim StrFolder As String, StrName As String, i As Long, j As Long
Dim strWorkbookName As String: strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
Const StrNoChr As String = """*./\:?|": StrName = "Certificate.docx"
StrFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator

  If Dir(StrFolder & strDocNm) = "" Then Exit Sub
    With wdApp
    'Disable alerts to prevent an SQL prompt
    .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
    'Display Word - change this to False once the code is running correctly
    .Visible = False
    'Open the mailmerge main document - set Visible:=True for testing
    Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(Filename:=StrFolder & StrName, ReadOnly:=True, 
    AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)

    With wdDoc
    With .MailMerge
      'Define the mailmerge type
      .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
      'Define the output
      .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
      .SuppressBlankLines = True
      'Connect to the data source
      .OpenDataSource Name:=strWorkbookName, ReadOnly:=True, _
      LinkToSource:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
      Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
      Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;" & _
      "User ID=Admin;Data Source=strWorkbookName;" & _
      "Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
      SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet1$`", _
      SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess

  'Process all eligible records
  For i = 1 To .DataSource.RecordCount
    With .DataSource
    .FirstRecord = i
    .LastRecord = i
    .ActiveRecord = i
    'Exit if the field to be used for the filename is empty
    If Trim(.DataFields("PropertyRef")) = "" Then Exit For

    Call DeleteBlankRows

    'StrFolder = .DataFields("Folder") & Application.PathSeparator
    StrName = .DataFields("PropertyRef")
  End With  

.Execute Pause:=False

'Clean up the filename
  For j = 1 To Len(StrNoChr)
  StrName = Replace(StrName, Mid(StrNoChr, j, 1), "_")
    Next
  StrName = "Certificate - " & Trim(StrName)
  Save as a PDF
    wdApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:=StrFolder & StrName & ".pdf", _
    FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
    wdApp.ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=False
  Next i

    'Disconnect from the data source
    .MainDocumentType = wdNotAMergeDocument
    End With

  'Close the mailmerge main document
  .Close False
  End With

  'Restore the Word alerts
  .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
  'Exit Word
  .Quit
  End With

  Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

New Macro

```
Sub DeleteBlankRows

Dim MyDoc As Object
Dim i As Integer

Set MyDoc = MyMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

  i = 2
  Do Until .Range("C" & i) = ""
    If .Range("C" & i) = "" Then MyDoc.tables(1).Rows(8).Delete
  i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

I only tried with 1 IF to start with to see if i could get it to work

Comment: Please show us what you've tried *in the code sample* and explain *how* it's not working. Also provide a small example of the data and the merge document - we can't look over your shoulder, so can't really answer the question in a meaningful way. You can use the [edit] link below the question to include additional, supportive information in the question, itself. **Also** please *indent* the VBA code in a logical manner so that it can be scanned better. Currently, it's very difficult to follow...

Comment: I have altered my text

Comment: *How* is the code not working? Why are we suddenly dealing with `WordEditor` instead of a `Word.Document`? How is the merge document (table, fields...) structured?

Comment: The code isn't working because the blank fields are still pulling through. The reason i jumped WordEditor is because in previous code i have wrote to delete rows in tables this is what i used to i thought i would re use it. link to document is https://drive.google.com/file/d/12xz4FAqOZW_IBS8Jd7nsllHY6w-GUJyb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Loftyyy Your DeleteBlankRows code is being called in completely the wrong place and, moreover, tries to process the document as if it's an email but with Excel cell addressing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has evidently been derived from code I've posted elsewhere, but modified without an adequate understanding of Word VBA. Try:

```
Sub RunMailMerge()
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim StrFolder As String, StrName As String, i As Long, j As Long, r As Long
Dim strWorkbookName As String: strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
Const StrNoChr As String = """*./\:?|": StrName = "Certificate.docx"
StrFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator
If Dir(StrFolder & StrName) = "" Then Exit Sub
With wdApp
  'Disable alerts to prevent an SQL prompt
  .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
  'Display Word - change this to False once the code is running correctly
  .Visible = False
  'Open the mailmerge main document - set Visible:=True for testing
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(Filename:=StrFolder & StrName, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
  With wdDoc.MailMerge
    'Define the mailmerge type
    .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
    'Define the output
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    .SuppressBlankLines = True
    'Connect to the data source
    .OpenDataSource Name:=strWorkbookName, ReadOnly:=True, LinkToSource:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
      Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;" & _
      "User ID=Admin;Data Source=strWorkbookName;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
      SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet1$`", SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess
    'Process all eligible records
    For i = 1 To .DataSource.RecordCount
      With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = i
        .LastRecord = i
        .ActiveRecord = i
        'Exit if the field to be used for the filename is empty
        If Trim(.DataFields("PropertyRef")) = "" Then Exit For
        'StrFolder = .DataFields("Folder") & Application.PathSeparator
        StrName = .DataFields("PropertyRef")
      End With
      .Execute Pause:=False
      'Clean up the filename
      For j = 1 To Len(StrNoChr)
        StrName = Replace(StrName, Mid(StrNoChr, j, 1), "_")
      Next
      StrName = "Certificate - " & Trim(StrName)
      'Delete table rows with $0.00 values
      With wdApp.ActiveDocument
        With .Tables(1)
          For r = 33 To 14 Step -1
            Select Case r
              Case 20, 28, 29
              Case Else: If Split(.Cell(r, 3).Range.Text, vbCr)(0) = "$0.00" Then .Rows(i).Delete
            End Select
          Next
        End With
        'Save as a PDF
        .SaveAs Filename:=StrFolder & StrName & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
      End With
    Next i
    'Disconnect from the data source
    .MainDocumentType = wdNotAMergeDocument
  End With
  'Close the mailmerge main document
  wdDoc.Close False
  'Restore the Word alerts
  .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
  'Exit Word
  .Quit
End With
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Note that I've assumed your 'empty' results will be output as $0.00; you'll need to change that part of the code to suit the actual output.

Comment: Thanks for this, I am still learning vba. I have amended the output but am getting a  "next with for" compile error. Any ideas?

Comment: @Loftyyy You should simply replace your original code with the (edited) code from my post above.

Comment: thank you so much for this, finally got it to work. you are a god